# Fastest way to count instances of substrings in string Python3.6

Tags: python, string, performance, bioinformatics, biopython

I have been working on a program which requires the counting of sub-strings (up to 4000 sub-strings of 2-6 characters located in a list) inside a main string (~400,000 characters). I understand this is similar to the question asked at [Counting substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307631/counting-sub-strings-in-a-string), however, this solution does not work for me. Since my sub-strings are DNA sequences, many of my sub-strings are repetitive instances of a single character (e.g. 'AA'); therefore, 'AAA' will be interpreted as a single instance of 'AA' rather than two instances if i split the string by 'AA'. My current solution is using nested loops, but I'm hoping there is a faster way as this code takes 5+ minutes for a single main string. Thanks in advance!

```
def getKmers(self, kmer):
    self.kmer_dict = {}
    kmer_tuples = list(product(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'], repeat = kmer))
    kmer_list = []
    for x in range(len(kmer_tuples)):
        new_kmer = ''
        for y in range(kmer):
            new_kmer += kmer_tuples[x][y]
        kmer_list.append(new_kmer)
    for x in range(len(kmer_list)):
        self.kmer_dict[kmer_list[x]] = 0
    for x in range(len(self.sequence)-kmer):
        for substr in kmer_list:
            if self.sequence[x:x+kmer] == substr:
                self.kmer_dict[substr] += 1
                break
    return self.kmer_dict
```

Comment: Have you try string.count()? It returns the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For counting overlapping substrings of DNA, you can use Biopython:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> Seq('AAA').count_overlap('AA')
2
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this method, see commit [`97709cc`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/97709cc7a4b8591e794b442796d41e4f7b855a0f).

However, if you're looking for really high performance, Python probably isn't the right language choice (although an extension like Cython could help).

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't looked into Biopython yet, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, once you are using extensions such as BioPython, performance is alright - what you can do is the algorithmic kernel in pure Python.

Comment: @jsbueno I wrote the Biopython implementation, it is pure Python, decent and useful I hope- my point is this is slow compared to say C- obvious I know, but method developers doing serious large scale k-mer analyses like this normally wouldn't choose Python for this (but it depends on their exact use case of course)

Comment: @Chris_Rands your code is certainly useful - it gets me above 100kb/s (compared to roughly 100kb/min before) when using 6-mers, which is more than fast enough for my purposes since I'm not working with eukaryotic sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Of course Python is fully able to perform these string searches. But instead of re-inventing all the wheels you will need, one screw at a time, you would be better of using a more specialized tool inside Python to deal with your problem - it looks like the BioPython project is the most activelly maintained and complete to deal with this sort of problem.

Short post with an example resembling your problem:
https://dodona.ugent.be/nl/exercises/1377336647/

Link to the BioPython project documentation: https://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation

(if the problem were simply overlapping strings, then the 3rd party "regex" module would be a way to go - https://pypi.org/project/regex/ - as the built-in regex engine in Python's `re` module can't deal with overlapping sequence either)